# Запуск проектов в PyCharm через консоль

Tags: windows, pycharm, ide

Я хочу чтоб при нажатии кнопки Run в PyCharm у меня открывалась не консоль IDE а консоль винды, это возможно?

Comment: Не знаю насчет PyCharm, но запуск через консоль - очень прост. Если неудобно каждый раз вводить путь к файлу скрипта - можно создать батник в директории проекта и запускаться через него.

Comment: Если пойти в меню Run, там будет Edit configurations... Можно так разное потыкать, посмотреть, что будет.